# iOs Websites: Target different versions of iOs (and also different versions of Android)

Tags: android, html, ios, css

For Internet Explorer, you can use conditional comments (or even hacks) to target specific versions of IE. Is there something similar for targeting different versions of iOs.

I have a website that works perfectly on iOS 4.2+ but it breaks on older versions. I can make it work on older versions by changing the CSS to hide some elements, but then it breaks for new versions.

I would just like to send my old iOS style sheet to older versions and have it ignored by newer versions.

There are lots resources for target different versions of iOs when developing an app, but there doesn't seem to be anything for websites.

As a bonus question, I would also like to know how to target different versions of android as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your detection of the device, browser, OS .etc. must be done using the User Agent string sent from the browser. It is the typical way to identify your user's environment. But I can understand that you're only serving HTML/CSS/Js so you have no back end code to do this.

My suggestion is that you conditionally download the correct CSS and JS file(s) using JavaScript.

you can get the user agent string by `navigator.userAgent` from Javascript, then you can download the correct files you want depending on the browser/OS/device you're running on.

See more info at 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

as per detecting Android versions. OS version '*should*' be in the UA string as well... Checkout this site for Android user agents.
http://www.gtrifonov.com/2011/04/15/google-android-user-agent-strings-2/

Comment: You may need some user-agent agnostic loading screen, because your page will look ugly until it downloads the correct files, especially on a mobile connection.